# What would the effects of drinking reverse gravity water be?

Tags: science-based, biology, gravity, water

If you drank a special type of water that falls in the opposite direction of gravity, what would happen? Since you can drink water while upside-down, it might just be the same, but I wanted to make sure.

**WORLDBUILDING INFO:**

- The world is a flat plane of floating islands, between two layers of clouds (which rain normal and reverse gravity water towards the island layer). The base gravity is 1G.
- "The islands themselves are supported by anti-gravity rocks, which give their gravity to the upwater in the opposite direction. This would normally result in 0G, but for each amount of water, it actually gets gravity from 2 amounts of rock! This is possible because the world is infinite" (From my worldbuilding document).
- This water is the only known material that has reverse gravity, though the floating rocks have no gravity.

Comment: As someone with bad acid reflux, I'm not sure I want to know :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: "What if X happened?" Questions are not a good fit for us, according to the [help]

Comment: Sorry for the open-ended, hypothetical question! I'll keep this in mind the next time I post a question. (BTW, this universe is flat)

Comment: The basis of your query is good, and actually is a worldbuilding question. I would strongly urge you to edit it. Give us some worldbuilding context --- what kind of world is this, how is this water contragravitational, is this kind of water unique or are there other contragravitational materials, etc. I'm extremely tempted to VTR simply because the VTC rationale is, in my opinion, not the right one. But you'll need to improve this question lest it be closed for a different reason! Also: you say the universe is flat. Please add pertinent details of that sort to your improved question!

Comment: Info like where the water comes from and the geographical shape of the world aren't really relevant when the question is so simple as "health ramifications of drinking water that falls up?" We shouldn't be asking OP to disorient their Q with these details. Short of a few relevant details I think this is almost good for reopen.

Comment: @BMF could you explain what details I should include?

Comment: @value1 I would recommend removing the bonus question part because it's a whole new question that should be asked separately. You'd get better answers that way. Is the world of <s>RGB</s> RG water in 1 g or is it different? Other than that, I don't see what else holds it back from being reopened, besides enough votes.

Comment: @BMF Thanks, I'll try doing that ;)

Comment: You seem to suppose objects have gravity as a kind of innate property. They don't. Wouldn't your anti-gravity water become normal gravity water once it passes the island layer?

Comment: Voted to reopen as the question seems a lot more complete (I'm not certain it's answerable still, but here goes).

Answer (score 2):

## You would die.

You'd have no difficulty getting the reverse-gravity (RG) water into your stomach. You can swallow water while standing on your head. Since the absorption of water is a chemical process, it would work its way into your blood stream and be moved around your body just fine.

The problem occurs when it gets into your cells. RG water and normal water would naturally segregate, with RG water at the top of your cells and normal water at the bottom, creating a zone of negative pressure in between them. It would prevent many of your biological processes from functioning because the chemicals wouldn't be able to distribute themselves evenly within a cell boundary.

The result would be massive cell death in short order.

Comment: A second way to die would be when all the water in our bodies is exchanged at which point we "fall" up into outer space and die.

Comment: Could the relatively high temperature of cells cause the diffusion of RG water molecules to overpower gravity and create a mostly even mixture? Does gravity even play a significant role at the scale of cells?

Comment: @BMF, Since RG water is imaginary, I can't answer that, but I can guess. You have to think of RG water as having a buoyancy that isn't mitigated by being in solution. Buoyancy is caused by a difference in density, and RG water effectively has negative density. Heat, in this case, just generates random motion. If you've worked with physics, you know that you can separate out horizontal and vertical momentum and calculate the factors that act on them independently. Higher heat would work against you, reducing the relative influence of Van der Wahl's forces.